# VRFv2Consumer contract request is always pending after requestRandomWords() in BSC

Tags: solidity, chainlink, bsc

I followed the ChainlinkVRF docs, modified some code of the VRFv2Consumer contract and deployed in bsc testnet which worked perfectly. Yet, deploying the same contract on bsc mainnet with the 1000 gwei keyHash and run the `requestRandomWords()` shows pending state forever. The pending state had been there for 2 days. I originally request 100 numbers and also tried 10 numbers after waiting for 2 days, but it still stuck in the pending state. Anyone had encountered the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

you most likely have not funded your subscription with enough LINK to fulfill the request. Check the [Subscription Billing](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/#subscription-billing) page of the docs to calculate how much LINK you'd need as a minimum.

Once you believe your subscription has been funded with enough LINK, suggest posting a URL to your subscription in the VRF channel in the Chainlink discord asking for your requests to be replayed, and someone will action it for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have solved the issue. It is due to the gas estimation was based on the gasPrice of the Gas lane key hash. Although bsc has an average gas price of 6 gwei, the gas estimation was based on the cheapest gas lane of 200 gwei. Thus, just make sure you have enough LINK for gas fee with gas price of 200 / 500 / 1000 gwei